# How can I extract a password-protected file a zip archive?

Tags: zip, password-recovery

I have a zip archive with several files. Zip can password protect individual files (not just the whole archive) and I have such a protection on one file.

How can I extract this file if I no longer remember the password?

Comment: Either you're leaving out part of the question, or you're including too much information: namely, the bit about the zip file.  Can you extract the PDF file from the zip file?  If so, don't mention the zip file.  Your problem is that you have a password-protected PDF file whose password you have "forgotten", period.

Comment: I can't extract the protected pdf from the zip. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: How can you even attempt to open the PDF file if you can't extract it from the zip file?

Comment: jjlin, I have modified my question in response to your feedback. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for updating the question, but I believe you still aren’t stating it correctly.  If you cannot extract the PDF file from the zip file, because you are asked for a password (which you don’t know) when you try, then it’s the zip file that is password-protected.  So your problem is that you’re trying to break into a password-protected zip file whose password you don’t know.  The fact that the file you are trying to extract is a PDF file is of dubious relevance.  It’s appropriate to mention it in the body of the question, but it doesn’t belong in the title, and the [pdf] tag is misleading.

Comment: The other file in the zip is unprotected and can be extracted and opened without a password prompt. Only the pdf cannot be extracted or opened due to the password protection. Therefore, I believe the zip is not protected. Am I correct? And do you still feel that the question is stated incorrectly?

Comment: No JJlin . Scott is right. If a password protected pdf is zipped it can not be extracted without providing the **pdf's** password.

Comment: Password protection operates on a file-level in a .zip archive, so each file can be protected or not by choice. zipinfo will show password protected files by displaying a capital letter in the file type e.g. `B` for encrypted binary files.

Comment: If it's old-style zip encryption there are several tools available to break the encryption, but if it's new-style (AES), then you're pretty much SOL without the password

Comment: @OP: I added the information you mentioned in the comments to your post. Please look at it and see if you agree. (If not you can always revert). I think it is clearer this way since PDF files themselves also can be password protected and that was a source of confusion.

Answer (score 2):

So there are a few possible answers.

First, if the zip actually doesn't have a password on it then you will be able to extract the pdf files no problem. then the issue becomes opening the pdf files with a password you forgot. Google "pdf password" and you will find some links to software that can remove the password, the one I have used costed $30.

Second, you are mentioning the zip, because you probably can't unzip it. If this is the case, then there actually is a password on the zip file. Windows natively can't recognize this. You need to install 7Zip, Winzip or WinRar. any one of them will prompt you for the password that you don't even know is there.

If you have one of those programs and the Zip file really doesn't have a password and it still won't unzip, then you still need to run a password removal tool on the zip file even though it doesn't have a password.

If none of that works, then you have a corrupted zip file. Not sure that's recoverable using basic tools.